# Change class name based on text of the next span tag

Tags: jquery, html, class

I have an html below:

```
<td class="status">
  <span class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  1
</td>
```

I want to change the span class to "fa-sun-o" if the class "status" text is 0.
The code that I have below doesn't work for some reasons. Can anyone help?

```
<script>
    if $(".status:contains('1')") {
        $('.status').nextAll('span:first').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o');
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an if statement for this. You can just do:

`$('.status:contains("1") span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o');`

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmJMBN)

Comment: Works like a charm! Many thanks for a quick response, Derek.

Comment: It seems that the code will not work if I took out the status class out of the td tag. How would I change the code to work if I change the html to:
 <td>
   <div class="status">1</div>
   <span class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</td>

Comment: add a `+` selector before the `span` because thats a sibling selector: `$('.status:contains("1") + span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o');` 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdPVvO

Comment: Thank you! I learn a lot. Didn't realize just adding a plus sign will do the trick.